# How to add background image for UIWebView without repeat?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I add background image for UIWebView like this

```
[self.webView setOpaque:NO];
[self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test01.jpg"]]];
```

The problem is that the image is repeated if UIWebView frame bigger than image size.

### How to add this image as background in UIWebView one time, without repeat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of `colorWithPatternImage:` says : `During drawing, the image in the pattern color is tiled as necessary to cover the given area.`

So two solutions :

- You put an image with the sizes of your webview, so it will not be repeated
- Use the a method to resize your image befor using `colorWithPatternImage:`

Here is how to resize an image properly :

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add UIImageView with same size and position with your UIWebView and set an image to it. For your UIWebView;

```
[yourWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[yourWebView setOpaque:NO];
```